# Make fails in Cygwin

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, x86-64, nvcc

after installing Cygwin I got in the directory where I want to compile and hit "make". This is the error I get:

> nvcc : fatal error : Unsupported host compiler 'x86_amd64'

What can I do now?

Answer (score 3):

Windows version CUDA works with MS VS C++ compiler. There's no support to make it work with cygwin-gcc.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements